# Adobe creative SDK not working for Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, adobecreativesdk

I have been using the Adobe creative sdk image editor for Android in one of my applications. The library was working fine till Android Marshmallow. After I upgraded my device to Android Nougat I am unable to open the editor and my app keeps crashing. This is the message I get in my logcat

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libcutils.so" needed or dlopened by "/system/lib/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"

I am using adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0 and adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.7.329. I also tried to upgrade to 4.4.8 and 0.9.7 but I still am facing the issue. There seems to be no documentation regarding API 24 for Android. My concern is a lot of users will have a problem once Android N is out for all phones.

Answer (score 0):

Android N (API 24) is not currently supported by the Creative SDK, but support is coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

The new version is out : v0.9.1186. They have added support for Android N
https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html