# App close when image selected from gallery AviaryIntent.Builder(this) in 7.0

Tags: android

I am trying to edit an image with the help of AviaryIntent.Builder
 it is working fine up to 6.0 but in 7.0 application is crashing

```
 Intent newIntent = new AviaryIntent.Builder(this)
                    .setData(Uri.parse(photoItem.getFilePath()))
                    .withOutput(Uri.fromFile(mEditingPhotoFile))
                    .saveWithNoChanges(false)
                    .withOutputFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
                    .withOutputSize(MegaPixels.Mp30)
                    .withOutputQuality(100)
                    .withVibrationEnabled(true)
                    .build();

            startActivityForResult(newIntent, REQUEST_EDIT_PHOTO);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.modal_activity_open_enter, R.anim.modal_activity_open_exit);
```

its is crashing on 
 startActivityForResult(newIntent, REQUEST_EDIT_PHOTO);

Comment: crash log or stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: app simply close and give no error in android monitor and not in run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk

It explains why you are getting the crash! Also I think the Aviary library you are using is referencing the platform library which is not allowed from 7.0 (mentioned in the link above).

You can reduce `targetSdkVersion` in build.gradle file as mentioned in the link.

EDIT: Check out this [Adobe creative SDK not working for Android Nougat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255690/adobe-creative-sdk-not-working-for-android-nougat)

Answer (score 0):

Android 6.0 and above need run time Permission
refer https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: i have integrate run time permissions